# Exporting polygons from GeoPandas to GeoJSON - end point is not the starting point

Tags: polygon, geopandas, google-maps, shapely, google-maps-api

I'm quite new to working with GeoPandas, and I try to export the file to GeoJSON, to later display it on a map using Google Maps Platform.

While GeoPandas Polygons do not have to end in the same point as the starting point, it seems that in Polygons in Google Maps Platform does (as I can see in the [example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)).

Is there a way to export Polygons to GeoJSON files such that it takes care that the end point is the same as the starting point?

Here is an example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Define the coordinates of the polygon vertices (clockwise or counterclockwise order)
coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 5), (5, 5), (5, 0)]

# Create a Polygon object
polygon = Polygon(coordinates)

# Create a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [polygon]})

# Specify the path where you want to save the GeoJSON file
geojson_path = 'path/to/output/file.geojson'

# Export the GeoDataFrame to a GeoJSON file
gdf.to_file(geojson_path, driver='GeoJSON')
```

Comment: Can not reproduce.  Geopandas adds the end point if you do not supply it so it makes a valid polygon. Coordinates output from your code: `[ [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 5.0 ], [ 5.0, 5.0 ], [ 5.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ]`

Comment: Even if GeoPandas closes your polygons for you, it's better to remain in the habit of always closing rings, since unclosed polygons are invalid everywhere else.